# My precision full wave rectifier is only outputting half wave; not sure why

Tags: operational-amplifier, frequency, precision-rectifier

I am currently using a precision full wave rectifier as shown below. The issue I have is that the output look like a half wave signal. Images of the input and output signal of the circuit is shown below. The diode I am using is [1N4001G](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/1n4001-d.pdf) and the opamp I am using is [LMH6611](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmh6611.pdf?HQS=dis-dk-null-digikeymode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1627668261299&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fgeneral%252Fdocs%252Fsuppproductinfo.tsp%253FdistId%253D10%2526gotoUrl%253Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Flit%252Fgpn%252Flmh6611). I would like to know how to get a full wave signal on the output. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Input Signal below
[image: Input Signal]

Output Signal below
[image: Output Signal]

Input vs Output Signal
[image]

Comment: Your input signal swings positive and negative.  Do your op amps have positive and negative voltage supply?

Comment: Is Vcm near ground acceptable to IC spec

Comment: Try adding bias to your signal or make sure you have a +ve and -ve power rails.

Comment: Input bias is not enough, you have to bias the Vin+ references on both Op Amps too

Comment: @JohnBirckhead The opamp is powered by battery; therefore, single supply currently.

Comment: If opamp are well supplied (+5V) ... change all resistors to 10k except one (the resistor that goes from the generator directly to the input - of the second opamp) and last resistor to 20k (or 2x 10k series) . Labelling is not a luxe, thank you. –

Comment: @Antonio51 The OP admitted to using using a single battery for the supply rails, about an hour ago. Just FYI.

Comment: Right. Just biasing also the 2 input+ to 2.5V (if 5V power supply). and alsi input signal.

Comment: How do you expect your opamp to handle input signals beyond its supply range?

Comment: @Sam You can use a single supply rail but you will have to add some passive parts to make that work (you need a mid-point voltage reference, for example, and more.) What is your battery type and voltage? And I hope you realize this isn't a perfect "ideal diode" but will have a little bit of jiggle at the bottoms due to the sudden output changes in opposite directions alternating twice per cycle and the difference in output current required for each half-cycle.

Comment: @Sam The "and more" I mentioned earlier is the need for biasing the input source up to the mid-point. That's another capacitor and biasing resistors to get there. Then you also need to re-bias the output back to ground, so that's another output capacitor and a resistor to ground, at minimum. With all that in place, you may get a passable output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNbW32.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The first stage of the full-wave rectifier is a half-wave rectifier giving out the inverted positive half-cycles.*

[image]

*Figure 2. Input waveform in blue. Output in orange.*

The problem is that you are using a single-ended supply and that means the op-amp can only output positive voltages.

[image]

*Figure 1. Internals of the ancient 741 opamp. Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier#Internal_circuitry_of_741-type_op-amp).*

From the internal schematic of the 741 op-amp it should be clear that the output can source current from the \$ V_{S+} \$ rail via Q14 or sink current to the \$ V_{S-} \$ rail via Q20. Nearly all (there are probably exceptions) op-amps will have a similar push-pull arrangement on the output.

It should be clear from the above that the lowest output voltage possible is when Q20 is turned fully on. The 741 is particularly bad and due to the proceeding stages the output can only get to within a few volts of V<sub>S-</sub>.

The LMH6611 you are using may be a lot better (I didn't check) but it can't possibly output a negative voltage if it is powered from a single 9 V cell.

The simplest solution is to add a second 9 V battery to provide the negative rail.

Comment: LM6611 is supplied from 2.7V to 11V max.

Answer (score 2):

You are not biasing these bipolar Op Amps properly with a single supply.

You have two choices:

1. Get a single supply OpAmp with PNP inputs that operate done to 0V on the input.
2. Add a negative voltage to both Op Amps and keep input within the Vcommon mode range specs.

### Other

Since you are getting only the +ve out on one half  cycle , most likely you are using a single supply not design for this operation.  This requires a certain type with PNP or Pch FET input that work down to Vee.

To reduce power, raise all the resistors above 100k.  then bias all the inputs above with low Rs >1k to Vbat/2.

Comment: I have added extra image for better clarification. I am only getting -ve out half cycle.

Comment: I already understood that. Did you understand my solution?

Comment: I am sorry. I did not fully understand your solution; I did understand that i need to use higher resistor to reduce power.

Comment: @Sam Tony's first paragraph: "you are using a single supply". You should be using a dual supply, i.e. positive supply voltage connected to the positive op-amp power pin, negative supply voltage connected to the negative op-amp power pin. You can also mid-point bias (Tony's second paragraph) the circuit if you are bent on using a single supply, but this requires more design work and not suitable if you are just starting out playing with op-amps. Another note, use small signal diodes like 1N4148, not big slow rectifier diodes like the 1N4001. Don't worry about your resistor values right now.

Comment: If you don’t have the proper IC, the easiest solution is add a battery for Vee instead of 0V. Even if only -3V

Answer (score 0):

You are getting what you should. Try an experiment with just diodes and you will get the same waveform (voltages will be different). Look at the scope where the input vs the output. The output frequency is 2X the input and notice when the input swings negative the output goes positive as it should. It is working as it should.

Comment: I think you've missed something in your analysis. See my answer for a graph of the first stage output; it's the positive half-cycles inverted. This goes to an inverting summing amplifier with gains of -1 for the input signal and -2 for the output of the rectifying stage. The end result is a full-wave rectified signal. The problem is that the rectifying stage can't swing negative on a single-rail supply the use of which was admitted in the comments.